# Tensorflow ValueError:Cannot feed value of shape (40, 24, 24, 4) for Tensor u'real_images:0', which has shape '(40, 24, 24, 3)'

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

When trying to implement a DCGAN i get this error message when trying to use my training function:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (40, 24, 24, 4) for Tensor u'real_images:0', which has shape '(40, 24, 24, 3)'
```

This error occurs when trying to use the line:

```
_,summary_str = self.sess.run([dis_optim, self.dis_sum],feed_dict = {self.inputs: batch_images, self.z: batch_z})
```

Any ideas as to why the tensors are different ? Below i have attached the code where i believe the error lies:

real_images placeholder (self.colour_dim is 3):

```
image_dimension = [self.input_H,self.input_H, self.colour_dim]

self.inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[self.batch_size] + image_dimension, name='real_images')
```

Segment where the error occurs:

```
for idx in xrange(0, batch_idxs):

    batch_files = data[idx * config.batch_size:(idx +1) * config.batch_size]
    batch = [getImage(batch_file,resize_h=self.output_H,resize_w=self.output_W) for batch_file in batch_files]

    batch_images = np.array(batch).astype(np.float32)
    print(batch_images)

    batch_z = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, [config.batch_size, self.z_dimension]).astype(np.float32)

    # discriminator
    _,summary_str = self.sess.run([dis_optim, self.dis_sum],feed_dict = {self.inputs: batch_images, self.z: batch_z})
    self.writer.add_summary(summary_str, counter)
```

The getImage and imread functions used:

```
def imread(path):
    return scipy.misc.imread(path).astype(np.float)

def getImage(im_path, resize_h, resize_w):
  image = imread(im_path)
  return transform(image, resize_h, resize_w)
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your image loading function is giving you RGBA images, while the network expects RGB images. Replacing `batch_images` with `batch_images[:,:,:,:3]` in the feed dict should be an easy hotfix, you can also look if your loading function supports giving you an RGB image directly.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks!